# Singular Spectrum Analysis Grouping / Forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I had a specific question about forecasting with Singular Spectrum Analysis and the impact that the grouping task has on this.
I understand that the grouping phase is important for interpreting the SSA decomposition. For example, if multiple components are describing the same seasonal cycle in the data, then grouping them together assists in how we interpret the model.
But I'm not clear as to whether this grouping actually impacts the quality of the forecasting results. Is grouping a task that leads to an equivalent model that is more readable as a human? Or is it actually a step that improves the model's ability to forecast?
Thanks for any thoughts,
Simon.